# Uniform convergence of difference quotients to the derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I remember being assigned the following homework problem a few years back.

> Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable. Prove that, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |h| < \delta$ implies $\left| \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} - f'(x) \right| < \epsilon$ for all appropriate $x$.

I also remember how I solved it.

> Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Since $f'$ is a continuous function on a compact interval, it is uniformly continuous and we can find a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-y| < \delta$ implies $|f'(x) - f'(y)| < \epsilon$ for $x ,y \in [0,1]$. Suppose $0 < |h| < \delta$ and that $x$ is such that $x,x+h \in [0,1]$. By the Mean Value Theorem, there is an $a$ between $x$ and $x+h$ such that $f'(a) = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$. Note $|x - a| < \delta$ clearly holds. So,
>   $\left|\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} - f'(x) \right| = |f'(a) - f'(x)| < \epsilon$ and we are finished.

What had me baffled was that this: we had not covered the MVT at the time the problem was assigned! This suggests there should be a way to prove it without using the MVT. Can anybody think of a way? I don't think I ever did. Thanks.

Comment: What's definition of uniformly convergence you are using? The definition that I know uses sequences, but here there is no sequence.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.
For $\delta>0$ let
$$U_\delta = \left\{a\in [0,1]\colon 0<|h|<\delta\Rightarrow \left|\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h-f'(a)\right|<\epsilon\right\}$$
Clearly, $\delta<\delta'$ implies $U_{\delta'}\subseteq U_\delta$.
By continuity of $f$ and $f'$, $U_\delta$ is open and by definition of $f'$, 
$$[0,1]=\bigcup _{\delta>0}U_\delta.$$
Since $[0,1]$ is compact, there is a finite subcover, i.e. there is a single $\delta>0$ such that $[0,1]=U_\delta$.

Comment: I'm looking at it for 10 minutes and cannot get why $U_\delta$ is open. It would be so for any fixed $h$, but how it follows when $U_\delta$ is effectively an infinite intersection of open sets (one for each $h$)?

Comment: @ybungalobill: You're right, more needs to be said.

Comment: In general, $U_{\delta}$ is not open, so this approach breaks down at that point. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4837736/990894) as to why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Some activity on the post reminded me of this 8 year old question. I guess one can add in that the desired statement follows pretty easily from the fundamental theorem of calculus. Choose $\epsilon>0$. Since $f'$ is uniformly continuous, you can choose $\delta>0$ such that $x \in [0,1]$, $|t|<\delta$ implies $|f'(x)-f'(x+t)|<\epsilon$. Then, if $x \in [0,1]$ and $0<|h|<\delta$ we get
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-f'(x)\right| &= \left|\frac{1}{h} \int_0^h (f'(x+t) - f'(x)) \ dt \right| \\
 &\leq \frac{1}{|h|} \int_0^h |f'(x+t) - f'(x)| \ dt \\
&\leq \epsilon.
\end{align*}
This gives another argument, but isn't really a great answer to the question since I'm pretty sure the fundamental theorem of calculus would not have been covered yet either.